# How do I set Outlook 2007 to download headers only for all users in a Terminal Services environment?

Tags: outlook-2007, windows-terminal-services

I'm building a Windows Server 2008 terminal services box for my company's disaster recovery environment, and I've installed Microsoft Office 2007 Professional Plus on it. What is the best way to enforce the downloading of headers only for all users (probably 30+)?

Comment: I am moving this to ServerFault. It's got a better chance of being answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some fiddling and reading, it looks very much like Outlook is smart enough to know that it is running on a terminal server, and will not archive the whole message. There are no .pst or .ost files in c:\users\me\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook.

Color me surprised!

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/965229) by Microsoft : "A hotfix enables you to set the download mode for IMAP accounts in Outlook 2007 and to configure the setting to sync the mailbox when you exit Outlook 2007"